# Is there any way to emulate accessing to my internal network - from a different network - while I'm in the same internal network?

Tags: networking, remote-access, emulation

Well, now suppose I had altered the configuration of my Cyberoam firewall so that -for example- I could access cyberoam login screen remotely WITHOUT actually going outside and try to access the login screen from a different network, I mean I want to try something like that without leaving my internal network, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a VPN? ....

Comment: @ DavidPostill thanks for reply , but would you elaborate in your answer ? because I'm a complete  networking beginner

Comment: Basically, the only way to get outside your network is to be outside your network. VPN just punches your network connection through a tunnel to somewhere else, and that somewhere else can be outside your network.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this "without leaving your local network " (almost by definition), but it.is possible to test from your location.

One way to do this is through a VPN from your computer, which transports traffic so it appears.to originate outside.your LAN - you will, of-course.need a VPN server outside your LAN. You may also be able to do something similar with a proxy.

An alternative I use is a cheat - just use cellular data.